# How to extract files from a folder, that are in a list

Tags: windows, cmd, explorer

I have a csv list of image names. 
I have a folder/directory with several thousand images in it, that I want to copy only the ones in the list from, to a subfolder.

Is there a method to go "Copy the files from folder1 to folder2, if they are in list.csv"?

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfortokens.php

Comment: appreciate the link, but it's on about getting IP addresses? I want to copy files?

Comment: Edit-in a sample of your `.csv` file

Comment: It's a link about parsing input with for /f and doing stuff with it.  Replace "ip addresses" with "filenames" and "spaces" with "commas".

Comment: I have a list that looks like this:     `0001108113.tag.01.jpg,0001108113.tag.02.jpg,0001108113.tag.03.jpg,0001108113.tag.04.jpg,0001108123.tag.04.jpg,0001108123.tag.05.jpg,0001108151.tag.04.jpg,0001108155.tag.01.jpg,0001108155.tag.02.jpg`    and a folder called Temp.      I tried `C:\Data\Marketing\Image Library>for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%A in extract.txt do copy %%A > temp` with no success. Sorry, I don't understand what to do here.